# RBAC not working

Tags: solaris, rbac

I`m learing RBAC in solaris.

```
bash-2.03# tail -4 /etc/user_attr
root::::type=normal;auths=solaris.*,solaris.grant;profiles=All
mirror::::type=normal;profiles=Mirror
jz::::type=normal;auths=solaris.*,solaris.grant;profiles=All
role1::::type=role;profile=p1
```

Check the 3th line.  I modified the account jz accroding to root. So I expecting the account jz have the same power as root. But it do not have. May I know why? Any thing more need to do? Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works.

Judging from the format of your `user_attr` file it looks like you're using Solaris 11 (that is, it looks the same as my S11 and significantly different from my S10 installs). In Solaris 11 `root` is a role, not a user.

- You should not be editing `user_attr` or any RBAC files directly.
- The recommended way to elevate to root is with `sudo` (`pfexec` and `pf`-shells are deprecated).
- The recommended way to modify roles and profiles is with `usermod`.

You'll need to add the profile `Primary Administrator` and the role `root` to the user `jz`:

```
usermod -P +"Primary Administrator" -R +root jz
```

You should remove the line you added manually before issuing that command. See `usermod(1M)` for more information.

Comment: Acctually, my os is solaris 8.  And I checked the root. It`s a user not a role. 

`bash-2.03# grep root /etc/user_attr
root::::type=normal;auths=solaris.*,solaris.grant;profiles=All`